# Algorithm Proofs

Tags: algorithm, proof, big-o

In this case, f(n), g(n), and h(n) are asymptotically positive functions, which means that there exists an N such that f(n)/g(n)/h(n) > 0, for all n >= N. Given that:

```
f(n) = Θ(g(n))
g(n) = Θ(h(n))
```

I need to prove that

```
f(n=Θ(h(n))).
```

It is suggested to use the formal definition of Θ, which states that if f(n) = Θ (g(n)) means there are positive constants c1, c2, and k, such that 0 ≤ c1g(n) ≤ f(n) ≤ c2g(n) for all n ≥ k. The values of c1, c2, and k must be fixed for the function f and must not depend on n. I have found examples similar to this such but am still unsure as to how to address this problem. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT:
My current guess is to try and use the transitive property, which states if a=b and b=c then a=c. I'm not sure this is exactly correct but it is my best guess for now. The syntax of the f(n=Θ(h(n))) is confusing me the most. I am not completely sure as how to interpret it.

Comment: As I mentioned previously, I am not sure where to start. I'm not looking for a complete solution, just a step in the right direction.

Comment: `f(n=Θ(h(n)))` seems like a typo (in the assignment?). I suspect that is intended to be `f(n) = Θ(h(n))`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that f(n=Θ(h(n))) is the same as f(n) = O(h(n)), then using Big 0 definition, which says:

```
f = O(g) iff exist c, n0 > 0 such that forall n >= n0 then 0 <= f(n) <= cg(n)
g = O(h) iff exist k, n1 > 0 such that forall n >= n1 then 0 <= g(n) <= kh(n)
```

then I can divide the last inequality and divide all members by

```
c: 0 <= f(n)/c <= g(n)
```

and substitute g(n) with

```
0 <= f(n)/c <= kh(n)
```

then multiply all by c, giving us

```
0 <= f(n) <= kch(n)
```

which is equivalent to f=O(h). So

```
f = O(h) iff exist j, n2 > 0 such that forall n >= n2 then 0 <= f(n) <= jh(n)
```

Comment: Theta is a tight bound, not only an upper bound. That is, `f = O(g) iff exist c1, c2, n0 > 0 such that forall n >= n0 then c1 g(n) <= f(n) <= c2 g(n)`.